# Can I use an achromatic focal reducer to reduce chromatic aberration?

Tags: observational-astronomy, telescope, amateur-observing, telescope-lens, refractor-telescope

I am using 75/1000 Plano convex lens to build telescope. Can I use an achromatic focal reducer to reduce chromatic aberration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focal reducer doesn't do that. In order to build an apochromatic refractor , that has minimal chromatic aberration, you need an objective lens assembly composed of 3 lenses. In order to reduce the spherical aberration and have a flat field, you need an additional lens element called field flattener. Hope this helps a bit